# How to joing or merge two dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I wish I could join these two dataframes by a column. Like this:
First df:

```
               Name             Points
1            Solange              38
2            Danilo               31
3            Lucas                29
4            Victor               27
5            Daniel               26
```

second df:

```
                  Name             Points
1                 Daniel             10
2                 Lucas              22
3                 Victor             5
4                 Danilo             12
5                 Solange            11
```

Result: (merge them by the name and sum the 'Pontos Totais' column, not necessarily sorted)

```
                  Name             Points
1                 Solange            49
2                 Lucas              51
3                 Victor             32
4                 Danilo             43
5                 Daniel             36
```

I already tried to use map, join inner and others, but the results have been quite frustrating.

Thanks

Comment: Are those the only two columns? If so, try `df1.set_index('name') + df2.set_index('name')`... pandas will align on the index and add the `Points`

Comment: Please, post a code which you used so it will be easier to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two possible solutions.
First dataframe is `df` and second dataframe is `df1`.

**First method : [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)**

```
pd.concat([df,df1]).groupby(['Name']).sum()
```

Output :

```
             Points
Name           
Daniel       36
Danilo       43
Lucas        51
Solange      49
Victor       32
```

**Second method : [`pd.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)**

```
df2 = df.merge(df1,how='inner', on ='Name')
df2.index = df2.Name
df2.sum(axis=1)
```

Output :

```
Name
Solange    49
Danilo     43
Lucas      51
Victor     32
Daniel     36
```

Comment: I took too long for this, but thanks.